# To set tag for multiple imageViews in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am developing an app for kids.

```
images=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"], nil];

NSString *dd=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", images];
NSLog(@"%@",dd);

randomIndex1=arc4random() % images.count;
selectedImage = [images objectAtIndex:randomIndex1]; //random selected image

NSLog(@"%@",selectedImage);

number = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10", nil];

randomNumber = arc4random() % number.count; //random selected number
NSLog(@"%d",randomNumber);

for (int i = 0; i <randomNumber; i++)
{
  NSLog(@"%@", selectedImage);
}

for (int j = 0 ; j <= randomNumber ; j++){
    UIImageView *iv = [_v1 viewWithTag:j];
    iv.image = selectedImage;
}
```

I have placed UIView inside my viewController. And inside the UIView there are 15 imageviews.To get the desired output i need to place the selected image inside the imageView based on the tag. How to achieve this ?

Comment: how do you `As got the selectedImage from the output` -- do this

Answer (score 0):

to show 15 images Use collectionView ,

In `itemForRow`

```
cell.imageview.image = UIImage(named:arrImg[indexPath.row])
```

To get selected Image

Use [DidSelectItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview)

```
print("image selected : \(indexPath.row)") // prints indexPath of selected image.
```

For more details , pls specify that thing in your ques.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use UICollection view for displaying images in horizontal/vertical direction? Also, use indexpath.item as a tag. Use collectionview cell to load all the images.
Store Images path/url in an array and load them collection view item for index path method.